# which platfom should I choose for a wiki like lexicon with moderation?

Tags: php, wiki

I need to build a lexicon with the following specifications:

- It has to be wiki-esque (versions, easy to contribute, term linking, etc.)
- Unlike a wiki, it has to have moderation (any registered user can contribute, but every contribution has to be approved by a moderator before publishing)
- Each term can have attachments (image & others)
- The general structure of a term page is predefined
- A general category structure is also predefined

What kind of platform (preferably PHP and open source) would you recommend for such a task?
Should I go with a tweaked wiki? if so, which?
Is there another kind of platform suited for my needs?

cheers,
Omer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) with ACL, but I haven't tested the a priori moderation.
I have a website for you : WikiMatrix, and its wizard. It will help you to chose your wiki : http://www.wikimatrix.org/wizard.php

Comment: thanks, though what I need is moderation and it's not specified in the matrix. I took a look and I think I'll go with the new Tiki Wiki.